# Proving the function is concave

Tags: calculus

$f(x) = x\log_{2}\left(1+\frac{a(M-x)^2}{(1+\frac{a}{b}x)(M-x) + \frac{x}{b}}\right)$ for $1 \leq x \leq M-1$ and $a,b > 0$.

Anybody can help me to prove that $f(x)$ is concave. I already try to take second derivative of $f(x)$ but it's impossible. Is there any shorter way to prove that $f(x)$ is concave

Comment: Have you tried plugging in $f((1-t)(x_{0}) + tx_{1})$ and comparing to $(1-t)f(x_{0}) + tf(x_{1})$

Comment: Thanks for your suggest. That's the proof by definition. However, it's quite difficult to try this way.

Comment: Since you changed your post, is there any condition for M ?

Comment: M can be larger than 10.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how much this could help you. I computed the values of function, first and second derivatives at x=0 and x=M. What I obtained is the following :

for x=0, f=0, f'=Log[1 + a M]/Log[2], f''=-((2 a (1 + b + a M))/(b (1 + a M) Log[2]))

for x=M, f=0, f'=0, f''= (2 a b)/Log[2]

So it looks that the second derivative change sign somewhere. I hope I did not make any mistake.

Comment: Thansk for your help. Actually, i already change the condition for variable $x$ such that $1 \leq x \leq M-1$

Comment: @user119062. Then, now, it becomes awful !